# How to show that $-|x| \leq x\sin\left(\frac1x\right) \leq |x|$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I know that:
$$-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$$
and
$$-1 \leq \sin\frac{1}{x} \leq 1$$

But how do I get to:

$$-|x| \leq x\sin\frac{1}{x} \leq |x|$$

What I tried is to multiply $-1 \leqslant \sin\frac{1}{x} \leqslant 1$ with $|x|$ and got:

$$-|x| \leq |x|\sin\frac{1}{x} \leq |x|$$

Comment: **Hint:**

For $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $-1\le\sin t\le 1$.

Comment: Note that you second inequality is not valid (not defined) for $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the formula $|a| \le b \iff -b \le a \le b$ with $a = x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), b = |x|$, the result follows.